# What does Order in iWork Number's graph inspector mean?

Tags: numbers

What does `Order` in this screen shot, from Numbers, do/mean? I searched the help for `Order` but couldn't find anything.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `order` is the order of multiple column as shown in the graph

If you have more than one column of data you can use the `Order` to select how they show in the graph

Selecting the `1` the first column will show as first of the 3 in the graph, selecting the `3` the 3d column will show in first place on the graph.

Here is a visual demonstration

Sample

[image: Sample]

Order set to 1

[image: order 1]

And Order set to 2

[image: Order 2]